# I Can't request a @Put in my android app with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

i'm trying to call a RestWebService using Retrofit, i can do the @get method but when i try the @PUT i don't have a response. My Restservice use x-www-form.

I try do use Logger but when the rest service is called I don’t have a answer so I can’t have a answer. Also I remove @FormURLEncoded and I try do send by query but I have the same answer

```
   private void saveData(String idFirebase, String firstName, String lastName, String licenseCard) {


        userRestService.getInstance().putUser("25yw345iHNbq8rmO8VOKhkKqv9M2", "Teste")
                .enqueue(new Callback<MessageResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MessageResponse> call, Response<MessageResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            logger.info("Webservice is working" + response.body().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MessageResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

```
public interface userRestServiceInterface {
    @GET("api/user")
        Call<userResponse> getUser(@Query("xifirebaseid") String firebaseId);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("api/user/{xifirebaseid}")
    Call<MessageResponse> putUser(@Path("xifirebaseid") String idFireBaseUser, @Field("xsnome") String firstName);
}
```

```
if (INSTANCE == null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://MyIP:3000/")
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        INSTANCE = retrofit.create(userRestServiceInterface.class);
        logger.info("Calling the Rest"+ INSTANCE);
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

I try to change the invocation method, and i use Postman with success.
I Android Studio give me this message

```
2022-12-29 21:36:35.168 12780-12810/com.swerve D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=521.57ms min=514.41ms max=528.73ms count=2
2022-12-29 21:36:36.680 12780-12810/com.swerve D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=504.05ms min=498.82ms max=512.63ms count=3
2022-12-29 21:36:37.704 12780-12810/com.swerve D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=512.04ms min=511.06ms max=513.03ms count=2
2022-12-29 21:36:38.727 12780-12810/com.swerve D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=511.20ms min=510.81ms max=511.59ms count=2
```

I try do do debug but without success, the service don't give any error message.. I try with and without x-www-form

Comment: How do you know that the service doesn't give an error message when you ignore a possible failure message? IMHO you should add at least a `logger.warn("PUT request failed", t);` to the `onFailure()` handler.

Comment: I already put looger but i don't have messages, because the system don't have a sucess or failure response. I only have this: D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=507.93ms min=499.81ms max=516.06ms count=2

Comment: Have you checked this in postman?

Comment: yes, In Postman i can update the fields with the same data in android.